# What is the height of an empty BST when using it in context for balancing?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, terminology

Suppose the datatype for a BST is defined as follows (in SML)

```
datatype 'a bst_Tree =
   Empty
 | Node of (int * 'a) * 'a bst_Tree * 'a bst_Tree;
```

So there are two cases one in which the BST is `Empty` or it can have a (key,value) as well as two children.

Now, for the case of an AVL where the condition is

> In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one
> <sub>- [AVL tree Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)</sub>

I want to able to create a height function for use to check whether the tree is balanced. My current setup is as follows

```
fun height (Empty) = ~1
  | height (Node(v, Empty, Empty)) = 0 (* Redundant matching because of third case *)
  | height (Node(v, L, R)) = 1 + Int.max(height(L),height(R))
```

I tried to separate the Tree into three conditions

1. A empty Tree
2. A Tree with a root node
3. A populated tree

The reason for this is that there does not seem to be a canonical source on what the value is for the height of an `Empty` Tree as opposed to one in which only has a root. For the purposes of my balance function it did the job, but I rather try to understand why there isn't a canonical answer for the height of an `Empty` Tree.

There is a canonical answer, in a matter of speaking on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_height#Terminology) but while initially doing research on this on Stack Overflow I arrived at many comments stating this to be wrong/incorrect/unconventional

> Conventionally, the value −1 corresponds to a subtree with no nodes, whereas zero corresponds to a subtree with one node.)

I grabbed the question from which my uncertainty appeared

[What is the definition for the height of a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209777/what-is-the-definition-for-the-height-of-a-tree)

> I think you should take a look at the [Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/) at the NIST website. There definition for height says a single node is height 0.
>
> The [definition of a valid tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/tree.html) does include an empty structure. The site doesn't mention the height of such a tree, but based on the definition of the height, it should also be 0.

Comment: Your case for `Node(v, Empty, Empty)` is redundant. It's already covered by `Node(v, L, R)` (given that `1 + Int.max(height(Empty), height(Empty))` is 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **height** of a rooted tree is defined as the **length of the longest simple leaf-to-root path**

In the case of a 2 node tree, then clearly this length is 1.

In the case of a 1 node tree (a tree with just the root) then the length has to be 0. (There are 0 edges on the path from the leaf to the root.)

In the case of a 0 node tree, well -1 doesn't make sense. It is a **distance** and must have a value $\geq 0$, but neither does it make sense to try and measure the length of `null`.

-1 is sometimes chosen because of its consistency with this recurrence relation for the height of nodes: (which is basically the same as what you posted above)

```
height(null) = -1
height((v, left, right)) = max(height(left), height(right)) + 1
```

but we could just as easily define:

```
height((v, null, null)) = 0
height(null) = 0
height((v, left, right)) = max(height(left), height(right)) + 1
```

Comment: Ah I could agree with that reasoning for 0 node tree being `null` thus it wouldn't make sense defining a value for it. It's basically an uninitialized variable. I like this

Comment: I have seen it defined as *the number of nodes on a longest path from the root*, which would result in your definition + 1. I don't know that any one definition is consensus, and the difference does not matter most of the time as one maps easily to the other.

Comment: @Raphael that's a fine definition also, but results in a single node having height 1.

Comment: @Joe Yes, and it seems more intuitive to me. If I have one block of height $x$, my tower has height $x$, not $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Any constant works as the height of `Empty`, because only the *difference* of heights is important for balancing. So, why not choose 0?

Comment: You are absolutely right, maybe I should have removed the context about balancing as it seems to be skewing from what I am confused about. To the gist of it: is the height of an Empty Tree 0 or does it depend on what application it is being used for? Wikipedia though, not canonical but widely popular for unofficial reference has the convention that -1 be used as the height